# Create a new dictionary in python with unique values based in the second parameter

Tags: python, dictionary, unique

I have a dictionary like this

```
{id : ['string',[1,2,3,4,5]], .....}
```

I would like to create a new dictionary with unique strings. 
But if we have strings that are equal, filter one of them based on the biggest average of the second value.
As an example, I have

```
{x:['ABC', [1,2,3,4,5], y:['ABC',[6,7,8,9,10],...}
```

in this case, x and y have the same string for the first value, but, the average of 6,7,8,9,10 is > than 1,2,3,4,5. So y would be appended to the new dictionary

Comment: What code have you tried? Python version?

Comment: show how should look the desired dictionary

Comment: The new dictionary should look exactly like the original, except with the filter unique values. Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
# exemplary dict
d = {'x':['ABC', [1,2,3,4,5]], 'y':['ABC',[6,7,8,9,10]], 'z': ['BCA', [1,2,3]]}
new_d = {}

for k,v in d.items():
    if v[0] not in new_d or sum(v[1])/len(v[1]) > sum(new_d[v[0]][0])/len(new_d[v[0]][0]):
        new_d[v[0]] = [v[1], k]

new_d = {v[1]:[k, v[0]] for k,v in new_d.items()}
print(new_d)
```

The output:

```
{'y': ['ABC', [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], 'z': ['BCA', [1, 2, 3]]}
```